# Xcode change color of menus and tabs

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to change white and gray color of Xcode menus?

like android studio *darcula* theme.

I went to fonts&colors section but it only have options for changing code and console colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

As per [Customizing the Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CustomizingtheEditor.html) chapter from `Xcode Overview` docs,  what you can change is:

- Choosing Syntax-Aware Fonts and Text Colors

> You can select from several font and color themes by choosing Xcode > Preferences and then selecting Fonts & Colors.

- Customizing Editing and Indenting Options

> You can change source editing and indenting settings to suit your preferences. Choose Xcode > Preferences, and select Text Editing to modify options such as these:
>
> Display line numbers in the source editor gutter.
>   * Automatically insert closing braces as you type.
>   * Suggest code completions while you enter code.
>   * Use spaces or tabs for an indent.
>   * Soft-wrap lines.
>   * Perform syntax-aware indenting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Xcode
2. Preferences
3. General (first tab)
4. Under Appearance drop down choose "Dark"

This makes my Xcode window dark and softer to my eyes.